Expert advisor running profit but also taking loss
I have written a code that I use to take profit in XAUUSD for 1 minute time frame. the problem with this EA is that it can make a profit when it follow the trend line, but when reversal came I keep taking losses, thus diminishing my profit. is there any way to fix my code ?
As you can read from the code, when the candle break above or below the moving average line, I will initiate a buy stop or sell stop action. the portion code down below is to continuously adjust SL and TP. after a long build up downwards / upwards, the graph tends to just move up hit the entry point, hit the sl and hit entry point again before it truly reverse it's cycle.
#property version   "1.00"
#include <Trade/Trade.mqh>

CTrade trade;
bool tradeExecuted;
double currentTP;
double currentSL;
double currentPoint;
bool orderCreated;
bool positionsCreated;
string positionType;
double entryPoint;
double stoploss;
double takeprofit;
int counter;
bool firstValve;
bool secondValve;
bool thirdValve;
int StartBar;
int BarsBack;
double lastProfit;
// test comment
string value;
int dealsCount;
MqlTick tick;
MqlTick Latest_Price; // Structure to get the latest prices     

int OnInit()
  {
   counter = 0;
   Print("On init");
   //PlaySound("news.wav");
   SymbolInfoTick(Symbol() ,Latest_Price); // Assign current prices to structure
   tradeExecuted = false;
   firstValve = false;
   secondValve = false;
   thirdValve = false;
   positionType = "Sell";
   value = "";
   dealsCount = 0;
   lastProfit = 0.00;
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {

  }

void OnTick()
  {

   static int  handleSlowMA = iMA(_Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, 200, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
   double slowMAArray[];
   CopyBuffer(handleSlowMA, 0,1,2,slowMAArray);
   ArraySetAsSeries(slowMAArray, true);

   static int handleFastMA = iMA(_Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, 10, 0, MODE_SMA, PRICE_CLOSE);
   double fastMaArray[];
   CopyBuffer(handleFastMA, 0,1,2, fastMaArray);
   ArraySetAsSeries(fastMaArray, true);
   
   double high = iHigh(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1, 1);   
   double low = iLow(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1, 1);   

   
   
   //if((fastMaArray[0] < slowMAArray[0] && fastMaArray[1] > slowMAArray[1])){
    if(counter == 0 && OrdersTotal() == 0 && value == "down"){
    Print("Fast MA is not < than slow MA");
    //PlaySound("news.wav");
      if (lastProfit > 0){
          double ask = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) - 1.0;
    double tp = ask - 200 * SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
    double sl = ask + 200 * SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
    //trade.SellStop(0.01,sellPoint,_Symbol,sl,tp,ORDER_TIME_DAY);
    trade.SellStop(0.01,ask,_Symbol,sl,tp,ORDER_TIME_DAY);
    positionType = "Sell";
    entryPoint = tp;
    counter = 1;
      }
      if (lastProfit < 0){
    double ask = entryPoint;
    double tp = ask - 200 * SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
    double sl = ask + 200 * SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
    //trade.SellStop(0.01,sellPoint,_Symbol,sl,tp,ORDER_TIME_DAY);
    trade.SellStop(0.01,ask,_Symbol,sl,tp,ORDER_TIME_DAY);
    positionType = "Sell";
    entryPoint = tp;
    counter = 1;
      
      }

   }
  
   
    if(counter == 0 && OrdersTotal() == 0 && value == "up"){
    Print("Fast MA is not < than slow MA");
    //PlaySound("news.wav");

    double ask = SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) + 1.0 ;
        if (lastProfit < 0){
    ask = entryPoint;
    }
    double tp = ask + 200 * SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
    double sl = ask - 200 * SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
    //trade.SellStop(0.01,sellPoint,_Symbol,sl,tp,ORDER_TIME_DAY);
    trade.BuyStop(0.01,ask,_Symbol,sl,tp,ORDER_TIME_DAY);
    positionType = "Buy";
    entryPoint = ask;
    counter = 1;
   }
   
   if((fastMaArray[0] > slowMAArray[0] && fastMaArray[1] < slowMAArray[1])){
      
   }


   Comment("\nslowMaArray[0]: ", slowMAArray[0],
   "\nslowMaArray[1]: ", slowMAArray[1],
   "\npriceClose:", iClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1),
   "\nTrend:", value,
   "\nOrder total: ", OrdersTotal(),
   "\nPositionsTotal: ", PositionsTotal(),
   "\nLastProfit: ", lastProfit,
   "\nEntryPoint: ", entryPoint,
   "\nDealsCount: ", dealsCount
   );

   // check if the current tick hit either the tp or sl
   // if hit, checkExecuted become false, prepare for another trade again
   //Print(OrdersTotal());
   //Print(entryPoint);
   //Print(SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK));

   // if new crossing occur but order is not converted to position, close current order
   if( OrdersTotal() == 1 ){
   // do this after some times have passed
   counter++;
   if (counter > 100){
   deletePendingOrder();
   }
   
   }

   if((iClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1) < slowMAArray[0] )){
   value = "down";
   }
   
   if((iClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_M1, 1) > slowMAArray[0] )){
   value = "up";
   }


   // if order has been converted into positions:
   if(OrdersTotal() == 0 && PositionsTotal() == 1){
   counter++; // starts counting timer
      if (positionType == "Sell"){

      // if the price had went into 200 pips from entry point, move the stop loss to zero point
      if (!firstValve && !secondValve && !thirdValve && entryPoint - SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) > 1.50){
            trade.PositionModify(_Symbol, entryPoint + 2.00, entryPoint - 3.00);
            firstValve = true;
            
         
      }
      if ( firstValve && !secondValve && !thirdValve && entryPoint - SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) > 2.50){
            trade.PositionModify(_Symbol, entryPoint + 2.00, entryPoint - 4.00);
            secondValve = true;
      }
            
            if ( firstValve && secondValve && !thirdValve && entryPoint - SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) > 3.50){
            trade.PositionModify(_Symbol, entryPoint + 2.00, entryPoint - 6.00);
            thirdValve = true;
      }
      }     
       if (positionType == "Buy"){
      // if the price had went into 200 pips from entry point, move the stop loss to zero point
      if (!firstValve && !secondValve && !thirdValve && SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) - entryPoint > 1.50){
            trade.PositionModify(_Symbol, entryPoint, entryPoint + 3.00);
            firstValve = true;
          
        }
      if (firstValve && !secondValve && !thirdValve && SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) - entryPoint > 2.50){
            trade.PositionModify(_Symbol, entryPoint + 1.00, entryPoint + 4.00);
            secondValve = true;
        }
              if (firstValve && secondValve && !thirdValve && SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol, SYMBOL_ASK) - entryPoint > 3.50){
            trade.PositionModify(_Symbol, entryPoint + 2.00, entryPoint + 6.00);
            thirdValve = true;
        }
      }
   }

   // if no order or position, clear up all variable
   if(OrdersTotal() == 0 && PositionsTotal() == 0){
   positionType = "";
   counter = 0;
   firstValve = false;
   secondValve = false;
   thirdValve = false;
   lastProfit = deal_profitY();
   }
   


  }

double deal_profitY()
  {

   ulong ticket;
   datetime closeTime=0;
   bool found=false;
    double deal_profit=0;
    //ulong order_magic;
     string   symbol;
   if(HistorySelect(0,TimeCurrent()))
     {
      for(int i=HistoryDealsTotal()-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
         ticket=HistoryDealGetTicket(i);
         symbol=HistoryDealGetString(ticket,DEAL_SYMBOL);

         if((HistoryDealGetInteger(ticket,DEAL_ENTRY)==DEAL_ENTRY_OUT)&&symbol==Symbol())
           {
 
            found=true;
            deal_profit=HistoryDealGetDouble(ticket,DEAL_PROFIT);
            break;
           }
        }
     }
   return ( deal_profit);
  }
  


void deletePendingOrder(){
     {
   int ord_total=OrdersTotal();
   if(ord_total > 0)
     {
      for(int i=ord_total-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
         ulong ticket=OrderGetTicket(i);
         if(OrderSelect(ticket) && OrderGetString(ORDER_SYMBOL)==Symbol())
           {
            CTrade *trade2=new CTrade();
            trade2.OrderDelete(ticket);
            delete trade2;
           }
        }
     }}
}

